# Can we have MathJax disabled for question previews, and active only for full question pages?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

It seems that the [questions page](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) (or the front page) does not render code spans in question previews.  This means that if a dollar sign appears in a code span (quite common in Mathematica), MathJax will try to render it as math:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

MathJax is very valuable, and I think it is absolutely necessary for this site.  But can we have some protection against these things going wrong?

---

Another example of MathJax trying to render code as math in previews:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I believe all formatting is stripped from the excerpts that are shown on the question page. The exception would be MathJax, which is processed client-side.

Comment: @David Do you think it'd be possible to disable MathJax for non-question pages?  (I.e. all summary pages)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible; all the SE team would have to do would be to remove the MathJax script element from the main question listing page template. The question is whether they would be willing to do so on this site only. Most other sites that use MathJax don't have this issue with dollar signs in code elements. I'm sure someone from the SE team will have a look at this before long.

Comment: After a few question with more math-formatting have come in, I'm not sure any more this should be done.  Ideally code spans would be identified and `$`s not MathJaxed there.